# How to share Entity definitions across multiple MarkLogic Entity Services

Tags: json, marklogic

I am using MarkLogics Entity Services to represent data. I am writing these definitions in JSON. Across the many Entity Services in the repository there is quite a bit or repeated code. For example a definition of an Address object exists within many entities and if I wanted to make a change to how that is defined while keeping the definition standardized I'd have to change every single Address definition. I found in the MarkLogic documentation a way to reference an HTTP endpoint but I don't understand how to figure out what the URL for a specific Entity definition is or if I even have my server set up in a way where those URLs exist. Here is the example given in the MarkLogic documentation

```json
{ "info": { "title": "Example", "version": "1.0.0"},
  "definitions": {
    "Person": {
      "description": "Example person entity type",
      "properties": {
        "id": { "datatype": "int" },
        "name": { "$ref": "http://example.org/Name" },
      }
}}}
```

To summarize: I am asking how to figure out what `http://example.org/Name` should be for an entity within my MarkLogic instance named Utility with a definition named Address